# いいです。turn down an offer?

Tags: words

例文:

> Aさん:　じゃ、土曜日も来ましょうか。
>   Bさん:　土曜日はいいです。

質問は、どうしてBさんの答えの意味は「都合が悪いんですが、、」と同じですか。Why does 『いいです』 mean "no"?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14613/1628

Comment: `Why does 『いいです』 mean "no"?` -- 英語でも "No thank you" って意味で "I'm good" って言いません？

Answer (score 1):

「いいです」または「結構です」は、「肯定」の意味だけでなく「否定」の意味もあり、どちらにも使用されます。

なお、「いいです」や「結構です」と言われたときは、文脈やアクセントによって理解することも必要です。

以下は幾つかの例です。ご参照ください。

肯定の例：

> **うん**、いいです**よ**。
>
> **はい**、いいです**よ**。
>
> いいです**よ**。
>
> **はい**、結構です。
>
> 結構です**よ**。
>
> **とても**結構です。

否定の例:

> **もう**結構です。
>
> **いいえ**、結構です。
>
> **まだ**結構です。